# post entry to IBM Connections board return existing entries with no expected headers or new entry

Tags: http-post, ibm-connections

Trying to Post Messages to IBM Connections using http POST method using c#.

ATOM formatted Message Entry Message XML:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="entry"/>
  <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/message-type" term="simpleEntry"/>
  <content type="text">I posted this from C# posted at :11:43 AM</content>
</entry>
```

URL is `http://--ServerName--/profiles/atom/mv/theboard/entries.do?key=e028cbd3-2126-455f-88b2-7e2cb4971e54`

This is from the Service Document where rel="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/mv/theboard"

I am requesting the service document, looking for the above URL depending on the user (Me for testing).

I am getting the list fine but when I POST, I am still only getting the list with standard headers but not the headers listed in the docs.

Here are the returned headers:

```
X-LConn-Auth :: false
X-UA-Compatible :: IE=EmulateIE7
Vary :: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive :: timeout=20, max=200
Connection :: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding :: chunked
Content-Language :: en-US
Cache-Control :: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type :: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
Date :: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 19:43:33 GMT
Expires :: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified :: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 19:43:33 GMT
Set-Cookie :: <<<<DELETED>>>> ; Path=/
Server :: IBM_HTTP_Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive also encountered this issue before.
I have made a ruby script to update the status to Lotus Connections. See details here:
[How to update user status message to IBM Connections (Lotus connection API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230814/how-to-update-user-status-message-to-ibm-connections-lotus-connection-api)